# Check the input parameters with groovy.mock.interceptor

Tags: unit-testing, groovy

I'm trying to have some unit tests using `groovy.mock.interceptor`. I want to assert that a function was indeed called with some specific values as arguments. I can't find how to do that. Any help?

This is what it looks like:

```
import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor
import org.junit.Test

class MyClassTest extends GroovyTestCase {
    @Test
    void test_correctness_of_passed_arguments() {
        def mock = new MockFor(MyClass)
        mock.ignore('main')
        mock.demand.myFunction{a, b, c -> '0'} // Is this where I should enforce the input params?
        mock.use {
            def foo = new MyClass()
            foo.main()  // <--- this is in there that it gets executed
        }
        mock.expect.verify()
        mock.demand.recorded[0] // <--- can I get what has been passed afterwards?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is doable as `mock.demand.myFunction` takes a normal `Closure`.
I ended up with something like this:

```
import groovy.mock.interceptor.MockFor
import org.junit.Test

class MyClassTest extends GroovyTestCase {
    @Test
    void test_correctness_of_passed_arguments() {
        def mock = new MockFor(MyClass)
        mock.ignore('main')
        def res = []
        // the mocked function stores its values in `res` and returns '0'
        mock.demand.myFunction(4) {a, b, c ->
            res.add([a, b, c])
            '0'
        }
        mock.use {
            def foo = new MyClass()
            foo.main()  // <--- this is in there that it gets executed
        }
        mock.expect.verify()
        res[0] // <--- I can then access the values there
    }
}
```

In the above example, I request `myFunction` to be called `4` times.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve expected behavior with `MockFor` class. Ignoring `main` method has one significant effect - inner method `myFunction` gets executed, but it happens without a presence of `MockInterceptor`. You can put a breakpoint in `groovy.mock.MockProxyMetaClass` class in the beginning of `invokeMethod` (line 74) and run a debugger to see what happens.

```
public Object invokeMethod(final Object object, final String methodName, final Object[] arguments) {
    if (null == interceptor && !fallingThrough) {
        throw new RuntimeException("cannot invoke method '" + methodName + "' without interceptor");
    }
    Object result = FALL_THROUGH_MARKER;
    if (interceptor != null) {
        result = interceptor.beforeInvoke(object, methodName, arguments);
    }
    if (result == FALL_THROUGH_MARKER) {
        Interceptor saved = interceptor;
        interceptor = null;
        boolean savedFallingThrough = fallingThrough;
        fallingThrough = true;
        result = adaptee.invokeMethod(object, methodName, arguments);
        fallingThrough = savedFallingThrough;
        interceptor = saved;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Invoking `foo.main()` method in the `mock.use {}` block invokes this method for non-null interceptor. The result returned by `interceptor.beforeInvoke()` is equal to `FALL_THROUGH_MARKER` because `main` method is marked as ignored. In this case interceptor is set to `null` temporarily and the method gets invoked in a regular way - it invokes inner `myFunction` method, but this fact is not recorded due to `null` interceptor at this point.

Basically, you treat mock object in your test case not as a mock, but rather as a spy object. Groovy standard mocking library does not support spy objects, but you can use e.g. Spock Framework to write tests using spy objects. The test you have shown in the question could look like this using Spock:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class ExampleSpec extends Specification {

    static class MyClass {
        def main() {
            return myFunction(0, 0 ,0)
        }

        def myFunction(def a, def b, def c) {
            return '2'
        }
    }

    def "should call myFunction with specific parameters"() {
        given:
        def foo = Spy(MyClass)

        when:
        foo.main()

        then:
        1 * foo.myFunction(0, 0, 0)

        and:
        0 * foo.myFunction(1,0,0)
    }
}
```

It executes a real `foo.main()` method, but it mocks `foo.myFunction()` method and records invocations and tests if the method got invoked with correct parameters - it records that it got invoked once with parameters `(0, 0, 0)` and that it was not invoked with parameters `(1, 0, 0)`.

**IMPORTANT:** If you create mock/spy objects from classes and not interfaces, then you need to add `cglib-nodep` dependency together with Spock.

Comment: Thanks for your time and explanation. I found Spock-related answers before, but I want to avoid using external libraries. :-) (not sure why you removed my "thanks" message in my initial question, though...)

Comment: Here's why thanks was removed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts